# launching Jupyter notebook"

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQssO.png)
I think I followed the installation instruction of Anaconda step by step, but the problem was that the Jupyter notebook couldn't be opened automatically, which is that site. Does anyone know how to fix it though?

Comment: Please post actual text of the error rather than a link to a screen shot. It will help other people who have the same problem find this thread and will make it more permanent.

Comment: Thank you so much,   this is the actual text I got  execution error: "http://localhost:8888/tree?token=df2aaf4b5809e2376be31da70c7a3458aa4e4a36f3c383b8" doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)
[I 13:25:36.562 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 08ac5957-2af3-459f-b085-99c679c41a95

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with the way OS X opens the default browser. You should be able to just copy the link and paste it into browser address. Everything should work normally. If you want a more permanent fix you can open the file located in your home directory `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` (it's just a text file, but it's hidden so you'll need the terminal or some app that can open it) and specify the default browser like this:

```
#  If not specified, the default browser will be determined by the `webbrowser`
#  standard library module, which allows setting of the BROWSER environment
#  variable to override it.
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'Safari'
```

EDIT: If you can't find the config file, you can generate one by running the command in your home directory:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Comment: Hi MarkM, That's what I wanted to ask about.    I've generated  that file by following the step of what you said.  Could this file be found in the anaconda file or anywhere else?

Comment: That file should be located in your home directory `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` Because it starts with a `.` you can't see it by default in the Finder. You can show hidden files in the Finder with `Command-Shift->`, but most people use the terminal app.

Comment: Also, you can re-hide the files by pressing the command shift > again.